# ASP.NET Generic UserControl with Html Content Placeholder

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This question might have already been asked, but I could not find any references to it so I apologize if it seems like a duplicate question.

What I'm trying to do is create a generic `DialogBox` as an ASP.NET UserControl; which would contain all the script required to create the dialog using `jQuery`. The dialog has a fixed set of buttons, but I'd like to be able to let the user define the content when they create the dialog. Suppose this is the markup for the user control:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // jQuery script to create the dialog
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div runat="server" id="divContainer">
        <!--Html Content Placeholder. What goes here?-->
    </div>
</body>
```

And the code-behind:

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Contents")]
public partial class UCDialogBox : ExtendedUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Page.DataBind();
    }

    public List<Control> Contents { get; set; }

    public DialogType Type { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And on the actual page after registering the control, I *would like* to be able to do something like this:

```
<uc:DialogBox runat="server">
    <div>
        <label>Hello World</label>
    </div>
</uc:DialogBox>
```

The problem with this is, `List<Control>` only allows for ASP.NET controls. Normal HTML controls (such as what I have above) won't work.

**Question 1:** What type should I use to allow any HTML control to be nested inside the user control? I tried `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl` but that didn't work either (ASP.NET says `The element 'div' cannot be nested within the element 'dialogbox'`).

**Question 2** What would I put as an HTML content placeholder on the user control which can be **bound** to the `Contents` property on the code behind? Something like

```
<SomePlaceholderControl DataSource="<%# Contents %>" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, putting HTML controls inside the body of the user control doesn't cause a run-time error. In fact, the controls come across just fine. I guess it's just the designer that whines about it.

As for the placeholder, I didn't have to use any specific control; I simply used an `HtmlTextWriter` to render the controls into a well-formatted HTML string inside a method that gets called in the markup:

```
<div runat="server" id="divContainer">
    <%# RenderContents() %>
</div>
```

And the code-behind method:

```
public string RenderContents()
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);

    foreach (var control in Contents)
    {
        control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    }

    return writer.ToString();
}
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the correct approach, I have added a ITemplate inside the Dialog control and placed a HtmlGenericControl container which is Div control with runat = "server".

Now you can add the html controls and text inside this container.

```
<cc1:UCDialogBox  ID="dialog" runat="server">
    <HtmlPlaceHolder>
        <div runat="server">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <div>Modal Content</div>
        </div>
    </HtmlPlaceHolder>
</cc1:UCDialogBox>
```

In custom server control you can get the container div content as innerHtml or innerText

```
public class UCDialogBox : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private ITemplate htmlPlaceHolder = null;

    [
    Browsable(false),
    DefaultValue(null),
    Description("Add your html contorls"),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)
    ]
    public virtual ITemplate HtmlPlaceHolder
    {
        get
        {
            return htmlPlaceHolder;
        }
        set
        {
            htmlPlaceHolder = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl placeholder = new HtmlGenericControl();

        htmlPlaceHolder.InstantiateIn(placeholder);

        var html = placeholder.Controls[1] as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;

        var result = html.InnerHtml.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim();

        output.Write(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with overriding `Render()` is that there are other controls on the page that I don't want to be forced to render manually. Using `List<Control>` did actually work, it was just the designer that was whining about it. Thanks though!